# Find array position using Button onclick in android

Tags: android

my array

```
String array1[] = menuname.toArray(new String[menuname.size()]);
array2 = menuid.toArray(new String[menuid.size()]);
```

my dynamic button coding

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l);
        List<Button> list = new ArrayList<Button>();
        for (int i = 1; i < array1.length; i++) {
            LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
            l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


            button.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            button.setText(" " + array1[i]);
            button.setId(i);
            button.setWidth(180);
            button.setHeight(60);

            button.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            button.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
            l.addView(button);
            linearLayout.addView(l);// if you want you can layout params
                                    // linearlayout
            list.add(button);

        }
```

`array1[]` contains the names of the `button`...and `array2[]` contains id of the button ....i want to set id and name for the dynamic button..how to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can just loop like you're doing and take values out of the arrays with i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set id for button in your code using

```
  button.setId(array2[i]);
```

Comment: I Got error..bcos my array value is string....it only accept integer..how to set it??

Comment: You can use Integer.parseInt(array[i]) to convert String to Integer!

Comment: @DivyaMotiwala- seems like you gonna earn all points by today itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `button.setText(array2[i] + " " + array1[i]);`? Is it something else you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `id` to your button at runtime and set `onClickListener` on that, you will get that `id` when the button is clicked.

```
if(nameArray.length()==idArray.length())
    {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuLayout);
    List<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>();
    for (int i = 1; i < nameArray.length; i++) {

        btnMenu.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        btnMenu.setText(" " + nameArray[i]);
        btnMenu.setId(idArray[i]);
        btnMenu.setWidth(180);
        btnMenu.setHeight(60);

        btnMenu.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        btnMenu.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);

        btnMenu.setOnClickListener(this);

        linearLayout.addView(btnMenu);
        list.add(button);
    }
 }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        super.onClick(view);
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case idArray[0]:
            // button with id "idArray[0]" is clicked
            break;
        }
    }
```